# Measure space and measurable numerical functions

Tags: measure-theory

Given a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ with finite measure $\mu$, and $f_1, f_2, \dots$ and $f$ measurable numerical functions on $\Omega$,
I'm trying to proof that statement $(i)$ implies statement $(ii)$.

$(i)$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ there exists an $A_{\delta, \epsilon} \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A_{\delta, \epsilon}) < \delta$ and an $N_{\delta,\epsilon}$ such that $f_n(\omega) \leq f(\omega) + \epsilon$ for all $\omega \in A_{\delta,\epsilon}^c$ and $n \geq N_{\delta,\epsilon}$.

$(ii)$ $\forall \delta > 0$ there exists an $A_{\delta} \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A_{\delta}) < \delta$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $f_n(\omega) \leq f(\omega) + \epsilon$ holds for all $\omega \in A_{\delta}^c$ and sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For the $A_{\delta}$ in $(ii)$ I tried taking the intersection of all $A_{\delta, \epsilon}$ from $(i)$, and I also tried the union, but those two didn't work.
Any ideas on how to find $A_{\delta}$? Thanks